# Como puedo actualizar el un mismo valor repetido en una pila cada vez que este aparezca dentro de la pila?

Tags: java, pilas, stack

Necesito que el valor que le paso como parámetro a la función reemplazar se actualice cada vez que este aparece en una pila, en el código que tengo, lo hace una única vez. La función debe recorrer cada uno de lo elementos y cada vez que se repita el parámetro "referencia" debe reemplazarse el mismo por el parámetro "valor"

```
    public void reemplazar(String referencia, String valor){
    // Consulta si el nodo existe en la pila
    if (buscar(referencia)) {
        // Crea una pila auxiliar.
        Nodo pilaAux = null;
        // Recorre la pila hasta llegar al nodo que tenga el valor
        // igual que el de referencia.
        while(referencia != inicio.getValor()){
            // Crea un nodo temporal para agregarlos a la pila auxiliar.
            Nodo temp = new Nodo();
            // Ingresa el valor al nodo temporal.
            temp.setValor(inicio.getValor());
            // Consulta si la pila auxiliar no ha sido inicializada.
            if(pilaAux == null){
                // Inicializa la pila auxiliar.
                pilaAux = temp;
            }
            // Caso contrario si la pila auxiliar ya contiene elementos
            // los agrega al inicio.
            else{
                temp.setSiguiente(pilaAux);
                pilaAux = temp;
            }
            // Elimina el nodo del tope de la pila hasta llegar al nodo
            // que se desea eliminar.
            retirar();
        }
        // Actualiza el valor del nodo.
        inicio.setValor(valor);
        // Regresa los valores de la pila auxiliar a la pila original
        // mientras la pila auxiliar tenga elementos.
        while(pilaAux != null){
            // Utiliza el metodo apilar para regresar los elementos a 
            // la pila original.
            apilar(pilaAux.getValor());
            // Avanza al siguiente nodo de la pila auxiliar.
            pilaAux = pilaAux.getSiguiente();
        }
        // Libera la memoria utilizada por la pila auxiliar.
        pilaAux = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Empieza por favor corrigiendo la manera en que comparas dos strings en `java`. La linea `referencia != inicio.getValor()` es incorrecta. Los strings en java se comparan usando el método `equals`. Debería ser `referencia.equals(inicio.getValor())`. Por otro lado, tienes un montón de métodos que no sabemos como funcionan internamente.

Comment: Me acabo de quedar ciego con ese comentario con letra más gorda que la carpa del circo del sol y en negrita. Por favor, un poco de *etiqueta* y *modosidad* al pedir ayuda. Que tu letra se vea a 100km de distancia no significa que vayamos a ayudarte antes, que los teclados están pegados a las pantallas hombre! PS: Estás comparando `String`s usando un `!=`?? `referencia != inicio.getValor()` Si es así... siento decirte que los `String` se comparan con `String.equals(String otherString)` y no con `==`, puesto que son Objetos, == compara sus referencias, no sus valores.